# opennebula upgrade unable to parse oned.conf

Tags: opennebula

I'm trying to upgrade OpenNebula from 5.10 to 5.12.  I'm on step 7 of [these instructions](http://docs.opennebula.io/5.12/intro_release_notes/upgrades/upgrading_single.html), but the database upgrade falls down:

```
$ sudo onedb upgrade -v
Unable to parse oned.conf: undefined method `chomp' for true:TrueClass
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here.  Is there a way to get more information about where the error is (which line in oned.conf, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

try

`onedb upgrade -v -S localhost -u oneadmin -p oneadmin -d opennebula`

with:
-S being the machine where you host your DB
-u most likely oneadmin user
-p most likely 'oneadmin' as a password
-d being the opennebula database name (most likely 'opennebula')

**Be careful, since 5.12, OpenNebula will not provide migration package to new versions unless if you subscribe to their upgrade program. Might want to look at CloudStack instead.**

Comment: Please edit your answer and add formatting to it (e.g. add code using "` `"). It will make your question much easier to read. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is a tutorial on how to format

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this? http://docs.opennebula.io/5.12/intro_release_notes/upgrades/start_here.html#community-edition

If you are running a **non-commercial deployment**, just use the form to ask for the **migrator package**.